# Printing single item of multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with my multidimensional array. I got two problems here: When I print my array, I get every object twice. And my next problem is I would like to get the result of one column for example: [strProductNaam] => Adjustable Dumbbells - Bowflex 552i - 2 to 24 kg. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

require('php/connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblProduct";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);


if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        $datas[] = $row;
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($datas);
echo '</pre>';



foreach($datas as $data){
  echo $data['strProductNaam'] ." ";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

Result after: print_r($datas):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [ID] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [CategorieID] => 1
            [2] => Adjustable Dumbbells - Bowflex 552i - 2 to 24 kg 
            [strProductNaam] => Adjustable Dumbbells - Bowflex 552i - 2 to 24 kg 
            [3] => 499
            [intPrijs] => 499
            [4] =>  Easy to adjust

            [strPlusPunt1] =>  Easy to adjust

            [5] => Saving space
            [strPlusPunt2] => Saving space
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [ID] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [CategorieID] => 1
            [2] => Dumbbell 15kg
            [strProductNaam] => Dumbbell 15kg
            [3] => 28.95
            [intPrijs] => 28.95
            [4] => Easy to expand

            [strPlusPunt1] => Easy to expand

            [5] => Easily adjustable
            [strPlusPunt2] => Easily adjustable
        )
```

Comment: _I would like to get the result of one column for example: [strProductNaam]_  You have a `foreach` for that, does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SOLUTION:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $datas[] = $row;
}
```

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($datas[1]['strProductNaam']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

in `sqlsrv_fetch_array` pass `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` as the 2nd argument. this will return only the named keys, and drop the numeric.

```php
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datas[] = $row['strProductNaam'];
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! And how do I select only 1 item of strProductNaam?

Comment: there are a few ways. one below `print_r($data[0])`
personally I prefer `current($data)` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current) as it gets the current pointer position and is not dependent on knowing the key.